# Spring-based Application not loading due to misconfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing an spring application based in a code from a tutorial, with the objective of learn about spring-security using database. My application, in this moment, is displaying an erro 404 when I try run it from Eclipse with Tomcat7. While in the browser a 404 error page is displayed, in the console of the Eclipse the follow message is observed:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

My configuration files are listed below:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>sdnext</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/sdnext-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**sdnext-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava.security" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

**sdnext-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

   <security:http auto-config="true" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"  
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, active from users where username=?" 
            authorities-by-username-query="select us.username, ur.authority from users us, user_roles ur 
              where us.user_id = ur.user_id and us.username =?  " 
        />
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

**database.properties**

```
database.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DAVDB?charSet=LATIN1
database.user=***
database.password=***
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

My JARS included in this project:

```
**aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc3.jar
spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar**
```

Someone can identify any error in this files? I spent many time with them, and still can figure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two context parameter named `contextConfigLocation` in your `web.xml`. To declare multiple context configuration files, you must seperate them with a space.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/sdnext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I had tried this, but don't work too. Anyway, I follow your suggestion and rewrite the code to this, and now I have the error **java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Mar 14 20:56:15 BRT 2014]; root of context hierarchy**

Comment: That's another problem, you probably have missing jar or jar with the wrong version. Are you using Maven?

Comment: I am not using Maven, but I don't think it's problem with the JARs. I was very careful with the inclusion of the JARs, for make sure I was using the corret version. My list in this point is added to question.

Comment: looking quickly, hibernate jars are missing.

Comment: I add this Hibernate JARs, but still happens the same error. If I understand correctly the error message, I should initialized this LifecycleProcessor somehow.

Comment: This error is often due to missing jar. It seems that cglib dependencies are also missing... And maybe some other jars. You might consider using maven if you don't know exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the last line of the stacktrace, it says:-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0': Cannot resolve 
reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

It seems like you defined that bean in the wrong file.

So, move `dataSource` bean from `sdnext-servlet.xml` to `sdnext-security.xml` first.

In your web.xml, you already have the following configuration:-

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Since the DispatcherServlet's `servlet-name` is `sdnext`, by default, Spring MVC will automatically look for `sdnext-servlet.xml` under `/WEB-INF` folder. That said, you can safely remove this configuration below from web.xml because 1) Spring MVC is already finding that configuration file by itself and 2) `contextConfigLocation` is used only by Spring, not Spring MVC, so there's no point exposing servlet related configuration here:-

```
<!-- Delete this! -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

So, your web.xml should have exactly one `contextConfigLocation` pointing to `/WEB-INF/sdnext-security.xml`, which you already have.